# Django form for REST API password reset

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

My situation:

Django app + mobile app, using Django REST api, and rest-auth.
I want to implement password reset transaction, launched on the mobile app.

The workflow I'm following is:

1) Execute password reset request from the mobile   -> OK, no problem

2) Django send email to user                        -> OK, no problem

3) Go to email-link page and create new password    -> OK, no problem
But the form presented to create new password is the REST framework API form

Questions

1) Can I customize this form? I have no idea how to do it since this URL is variable (with UID and token). Any suggestions?

2) Is this workflow suitable, or is there a better way to manage the reset password workflow?

In my URL file I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

Should I create here a custom view?

In the Django REST documentation it says REST framework is suitable for returning both API style responses, and regular HTML pages. But I could not find a suitable example that helps me for my case.

Comment: You better not use Django form altogether, Django rest supports form it was meant to retain some familiarity. You'll have good time while keeping the API only to return Json while you can use your front end framework's form library.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution
For those who might have the same problem:

Basically I didn't realize there is one workflow for password reset in allauth and another via rest_auth with some differences on the link-tokens used on emails

The workflow in allauth is ok for my needs (the one from rest_auth requires to use the browsable api forms), just needed to initiate it from an initial request from a rest_auth request which I solved with this code in my views.py:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, 
permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from allauth.account.forms import ResetPasswordForm

@api_view(['POST'])    
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def recover_password(request):
    if request.data.get('email'):
        form = ResetPasswordForm({'email': request.data.get('email')})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request)
            return Response('Email with instructions was sent to provided account', 
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response('Missing email', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The function receives email and launches an allauth workflow